# Is my service definition right in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myApp',[])
})();

(function(){
    angular.module('myApp.dashboard',[])
})();

(function(){
    angular.module('myApp.value',[])
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.value').service('whichToShow',function(){
        alert("running2");
        var logged=true;
        return {
            getVar: function(){
                return logged;
            },
            setVar: function(value){
                logged=value;
            }

        };
    });
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.dashboard').controller('mainControl',mainControl);

    mainControl.$inject = ['whichToShow'];
    alert("running1");
    function mainControl(whichToShow){
        this.logged=whichToShow.getVar();
        alert(this.logged);

    };
})();
```

I am writing one app imitating another finished app, but I can't use my new defined service. I am writing according to his code https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp/blob/master/js/all.js
Could you tell me which part should I modify? You had better change on my code, so that I can know why mine is wrong. Thanks!

you can see all my code here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YeahrG28bT2izX8gMKor?p=preview
I haven't done much about that, what I want now is to make some buttons invisible

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? What happens that you don't want to happen? What doesn't happen that you want to happen? Note the all relevant code, in an [mcve], should be included in the question itself, not a third-party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is a `factory`.
To define a service, you have to get the instance and enrich it with methods.

So, you can change your `service` into a `factory` like this :

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.value').factory('whichToShow',function(){
        alert("running2");
        var logged=true;
        return {
            getVar: function(){
                return logged;
            },
            setVar: function(value){
                logged=value;
            }

        };
    });
})();
```

Or, define your `service` like this:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.value').service('whichToShow',function(){

        var logged=true;
        this.getVar = function(){
                return logged;
            };
        this.setVar =function(value){
                logged=value;
            };
    });
})();
```

**Edit 1:**

Your plunker code is not correct.
Please, check this correction : https://plnkr.co/edit/2HAwy7MV4dK0yUuBcCfG?p=preview

- Your inclusion of `all.js` was pointing to `js/all.js` instead of just `all.js`.
- In your `mainControl`, Your injection wasn't correct.

Comment: Master, do you know why your modification has not running2 alert?

Comment: Can I put them in the different module? and how to use inject here?

Comment: @fourth please refer to the `mainControl` definition in my correction.

Comment: can you see this? https://github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp/blob/master/js/all.js I was writing according to this. He wrote it in my way and works well.

Comment: at github.com/PatrickO10/meetUp/blob/master/js/all.js#L285 there is one service

Comment: I figure it out, I should put all module in the definition of myApp

Answer (score 1):

Your **whichToShow** is defined in *myApp.value* module, but used in *myApp.dashboard* module. You need just add reference to *myApp.value* module when declaring *myApp.dashboard* module.

```
angular.module('myApp.dashboard',['myApp.value'])
```

Comment: You are partially right, I put all in the definition of myApp, then it works